# Angular.JS ng-model

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have this code:

HTML

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app=EmployeeApp>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>favly</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles_index.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,900,100,300,700,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/search_folder.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="empCtrl">
    <div id="leftMenu">
     <div id="searchFoldersList"><span class="icon-search search"></span><input ng-model="fold.Folder" type="text" placeholder="Search..." /></div>
     <div id="foldersList">
         <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="fold in folder">{{fold.Folder}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     <div id="addFolderBox"><span class="icon-add plus"></span> ADD NEW FOLDER</div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightContent">
        <div id="menuContent">
         <ul>
             <li><span class="icon-list"></span></li>
                <li><span class="icon-settings"></span></li>
                <li><span class="icon-account-circle"></span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this on JS:

```js
  var employeeApp = angular.module("EmployeeApp",[]);
  employeeApp.controller("empCtrl",function($scope, $http){
   $http.get("folders_list.php").success(function (response) {$scope.folder = response.folders;});             
  });
```

And folders_list.php scope this:

{"records":[{"Folder":"Juegos"},{"Folder":"PerifÃ©ricos"}]}

Ok my code works and show the Folder's name, but my problem is I don't know why the input don't search on those "li" to find the word entered. I think it's because my ng-model is incorrect, but I don't know what ng-model type.

Thanks!

Comment: You should use filtering, for your <input> `<input ng-model="searchFolder" type="text" placeholder="Search..." />` then in your ng-repeat directive use `<li ng-repeat="fold in folder | filter: searchFolder">{{fold.Folder}}</li>`

Comment: Yes it was that! I'm new on Angular.js and I'm trying to improve day by day, thank you so much for help me :)

Comment: Cool! Keep it up! and also you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Should this be response.records ?

From

```
$http.get("folders_list.php").success(function (response) {$scope.folder = response.records;});
```

instead of

```
$http.get("folders_list.php").success(function (response) {$scope.folder = response.folders;});
```